# Cognos 11 - Pass Through Errors

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

My team has taken over  some applications that were developed around 10 years ago.  We are mainly for sustainment; however, there is also some development going on, primarily for security issues.  On our Cognos server, we were required to upgrade from 10.2 to 11.  Our server administrator installed Cognos 11; however, our previously working Single Sign-On (SSO) stopped working.  We submitted a ticket to our IT services who said that it was out of their hands and asked us to fix it.  This  was months ago and there has been no progress.  Our IT dept. put a ticket in with IBM and they asked the following:

```
1. For 441 (Cognos SSO Errors) errors, have you added pass through error in the bottom of the gateway configuration document?

2. What have the 441 errors resolved to?


3. What pass through method are you using to send authentication from "another site"? Service provider shibboleth, openid connect, etc.?
```

Does anyone know where I can find the gateway configuration document and where the pass through errors would be?

Also, how can I tell what they resolve to?  I monitored my network traffic from my browser when trying to login but only see the 441, I guess the "resolving happens on the server" but I'm not sure where to find it.

Does anyone know how I can find the service provider they mention in question 3?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Two years ago I upgraded Cognos, with SSO, from 10.2.1 to 11.0.4.  I've never heard the terms in your IT department's email.  Cognos SSO is specific to the software being used for the gateway.  What OS and web server are you running?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  We are using Windows Server 2012 and IIS web server (I don't think I have access to that but I'm not sure how to check).

Answer (score 0):

To use IIS as a Cognos gateway for Single Sign On for IBM Cognos 11.0.4 and later, use this document from IBM

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_11.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.inst_cr_winux.doc/t_gateway_iis.html#t_sso_actdirserver